# Linker unable to find object references when using gtest (C++)

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cmake, linker, googletest

I decided to get started with unit tests and wrote my first one using gtest. Here's the source:

DetectorTests.cpp:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

#include <ros_layer/utils/DetectorUtils.h>



class DetectorTests : public ::testing::Test {
 public:
  DetectorTests() {
  }

  bool initTestFixture() {
    return true;
  }

  virtual void SetUp() {
    ASSERT_TRUE(initTestFixture());
  }

  virtual void TearDown() {
  }

};

// Test where the robot does a vector operation
TEST_F(DetectorTests, testNoDetect) {
  // Parameters get set up here
  ros::NodeHandle privateNodeHandle("~");
  std::shared_ptr<ros_layer::DetectorUtils> distDetector = std::make_shared<ros_layer:DetectorUtils>(privateNodeHandle);

  // @to-do set up object parameters before running test
  ASSERT_FALSE(distDetector->checkReadings());
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  ros::init(argc, argv, "detection_action_test");
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

My CMakeLists.txt has the following lines:

```
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
catkin_add_gtest(detector-test test/DetectorTests.cpp)
target_link_libraries(detector-test ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

When I run CMake with the arguments to run the tests though, I get this error while linking:

```
In function `construct<ros_layer::DetectorUtils, ros::NodeHandle&>':
/code/include/c++/4.8/ext/new_allocator.h:120: undefined reference to `ros_layer::DetectorUtils::DetectorUtils(ros::NodeHandle&)'
CMakeFiles/detector-test.dir/test/DetectorTest.cpp.o: In function `destroy<ros_layer::DetectorUtils>':
/code/include/c++/4.8/ext/new_allocator.h:124: undefined reference to `ros_layer::DetectorUtils::~DetectorUtils()'
```

If I remove all the unit test related code and just write c++ with the DetectorUtils object being created, I have no trouble at all. What's causing this error and how do I resolve it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ROS, so just a general advice: check the place in your code where `ros_layer::DetectorUtils::DetectorUtils(ros::NodeHandle&)` is actually defined, check that it is defined in some object file and check the order of libraries given to the linker.

Comment: It's defined. When I create the object using the same line without any gtest stuff in the code, it compiles just fine.

Comment: If it is the linking problem, the exact command line for linking (`make VERBOSE=1`) could be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. target_link_libraries in my CMakeLists needed to have the library that DetectorUtils is defined in. Here's the updated line:

```
target_link_libraries(dragging-test ROSLayerLibrary ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```